# Como deserializar correctamente JSON en Axios ([object%20Object])

Tags: javascript, asp, axios

Tengo un error al querer ejecutar un método de tipo **PUT**
entiendo que tengo un problema con la deserialización del objeto pero no se solucionarlo.

Estoy obteniendo el error **[object%20Object]** en donde el formato del json parece que no está siendo enviado correctamente y el back lo recibe mal.

este es parte del front-end

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Alerta from "./Alerta";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import { Modificar } from "../services/usuario";

const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const payload = {
      Detalle: detalle,
      Precio: precio,
    };

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth}`
      }
    };
 };
```

```html
<div className='campo'>
  <label htmlFor="nombre">Precio</label>
  <input id="PRECIO" type="text" placeholder="precio" value={precio} />
</div>

<div className='campo'>
  <label htmlFor="apellido">detalle</label>
  <input id="detalle" type="text" placeholder="detalle" value={detalle} />
</div>
```

este es el metodo del back al que el front llama

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Modificar(int id, [FromBody] Producto producto)
    {            
        if (id != usuario.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        Producto prod = await _Precios.Modificar(producto);
        return Ok(Producto);
    }
```

[image: ERROR]

muchas gracias